# Stop events triggering on the child nodes

Tags: javascript

I have written a program for a drop down menu, I want the code to go from display `block` to `none` on a `mouse out` but the `mouse out` event is triggered even on its child nodes I want to prevent that from happening
what are the possible solutions ?

---

CSS

```
.dropdown{
        list-style: none;
        display: none;
        position: absolute; 
        background-color: skyblue;
    }
```

---

HTML

```
<button>Home</button>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <ul class="">
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contacts</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Other</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
        var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown')[0];
        var ddChildNodes = document.querySelector('li');

        button.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
            dropdown.style.display='block';
        },false);

        dropdown.addEventListener('mouseout',
            function(){
                    dropdown.style.display='none';
            },false);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

With [most modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) (and even ancient IE), you can use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`. `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` don't bubble.

Support:

- IE 5.5+
- Firefox 10+
- Chrome 30+

Comment: had no idea mouseenter and mouseleave didn't bubble! ;)